# Token Based registration with Ruby on Rails without storing token into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, registration

I am making an app in Ruby on Rails, that have Users. If a current User want to invite someone to register at my site, he will send invitation. A registration link will be sent to that invitee. But Link provided should only work for that user (or in other words, only valid for that particular email). Futhermore, we don't want to store that url in database with that email (to be free of worry from attacks like SQL injection, etc). This registration should occur using a authenticated token. Is there any method through which this is possible ?

Requirements:
1) Url/token based registration
2) unique url/token for each email
3) don't store url/token in database

Comment: It is possible, but will be very unsafe. Much better way is to store token in DB, and if you do this proper way, then it will be much safer and easier.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, lets say if we don't store it in DB, how will it be done? Shall I encode the email into the url and then when request is made we shall decode it again?